# Wikitude create image overlay on scanned image

Tags: android, wikitude

I want to show one image on top of target image after successful image recognition from wikitude cloud.I have used on click wikitude cloud recognition sample code provided by sdk.How to achieve this using native android sdk for wikitude?

Comment: Please describe more about the question and you can find every thing in wikitude sdk docs

Comment: @MilindVyas  have gone through docs it can be achieved using java script sdk but  how same can be achieved native android wikitude sdk like ARImageResource class exist in javascript sdk what is it alternative in native android sdk?

Comment: I am suggested to use Vuforiya plugin for AR this is really awesome sdk for AR

Comment: @MilindVyas I have to use wikitude sdk only so this can be achieved using javascript only please compare cloud recognition docs both for native android sdk for wikitude and java script android sdk for wikitude.You will get my point.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer using xml, try this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"/>
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/image2"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

If you are using code, try this:

```
FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
ImageView image1 = ...
ImageView image2 = ...


FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
i.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 
frame.addView(image1);
frame.addView(image2);
```

Comment: David this is AR question . he want to make AR application in which he want to overlay image if camera fetch image .

Comment: @MilindVyas, if that is the case, he should NOT tag it with "Android".

Comment: Yeah thats also true brother ! i can understand here is some confusion well cheers! may be your ans will helpful  to other person

Comment: @MilindVyas, the OP mentions "using native android sdk for wikitude", so I suppose you might misunderstand this?

Comment: No I already work in wikitude and vuforia sdks for making AR application so i got the question on first sight

Comment: @MilindVyas, maybe let the OP clarify this? :)